# Algolia with Custom Magento Theme (Ultimo)

Tags: search, themes, magento-1.9, algolia

We are using the Ultimo theme for Magento 1.9.2.4 and have Algolia 1.6 installed. We can access the Algolia settings and even see source code on our homepage, however the standard Magento search box is not replaced by Algolia like it generally is. We cannot access the search page and when turning on "replace categories page", our category pages go blank.

My thought is that Algolia isn't activating correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Re. search box, in the Algolia Advanced settings tab in Magento's admin see what's set as your Search input DOM Selector.

A value of `#search` will add autocomplete onto the Ultimo search box. A value of `.algolia-search-input` will utilise the Algolia box.